# do not create spring bean during integration testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Config class which I want to have it loaded when the application is running.

```
@Configuration
public class EventHubConfiguration {


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(...)
    public EventHubClient someClient(final String namespace,
                                     final String eventHubName,
                                     final String sasKeyName,
                                     final String sasKey) throws IOException, EventHubException {
        ConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new ConnectionStringBuilder()
                .setNamespaceName(namespace)
                .setEventHubName(eventHubName)
                .setSasKeyName(sasKeyName)
                .setSasKey(sasKey);
        return EventHubClient.createSync(connStr.toString(), Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor());
    }
}
```

But how can I prevent it from loading when my integration tests are running. For example when I do `mvn clean test` or as part of my build. I don't wish the eventhub client to be created during my integration testing.

Comment: Use separate profile, or mock that bean first, provide another mock implementation in test context using `@Primary` + `@Bean`, use `@ConditionalOn(...)` variant that suits you, and probably many more ways that I am not aware of

Comment: for the DI container to work you need a bean, even if it is only a test dummy.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in spring doc :
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing

> 3.2.2. Dependency Injection of Test Fixtures
> When the TestContext framework loads your application context, it can optionally configure instances of your test classes by using Dependency Injection. This provides a convenient mechanism for setting up test fixtures by using preconfigured beans from your application context.

So yes your test class must be a bean